# Show that multiplication map between Lebesgue Spaces in bounded in the $L^{r}$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $T:L^{q}(\mathbb{R})\to L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ be a bounded linear map via $f \mapsto \gamma f$
where $1\leq p < q <+ \infty$.Here $\gamma: \mathbb{R}\to
\mathbb{R}$ measurable.

Show that $\gamma \in L^{r}(\mathbb{R})$ where $r=\frac{pq}{q-p}$.

I'm trying to prove by contradiction. i.e begin by assuming that$\gamma \notin L^{r}(\mathbb{R})$.
Now I want to find a bounded subsequence $(u_{n})$ in $L^{q}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(\gamma u_{n})$ is unbounded in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$, thus contradicting the assumption that $T$ is bounded. I am struggling to find an appropriate sequence.

It might be helpful to note that we have $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}$. So, by Holder inequality, we have $\|fg\|_{p} \leq \|f\|_{q}\|g\|_{r}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you mean $1/q + 1/r = 1/p$. This seems to be Theorem 1.3 in [this](https://books.google.dk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=CT0bCAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA321&ots=vnTz0aIWtZ&sig=jBANFNRYo4mXYCzXCKiugteGIEs&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) article by Takagi and Yokouchi.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error and for the article @Danny .